# TestCafé: How to use typeText without selector

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have two questions about the `typeText` function.

1. According to the docs, I need two arguments: the selector and text to type. However, I'm testing an app that automatically sets focus on an input element and I can't rely on its ID, class or whatever the `Selector` would need. I just want to type, like in Cypress, without selecting something first. Is this possible?
2. The `typeText` method also requires the second parameter (the text). But sometimes, I don't want to put any text into a field (for example testing a login component). Right now, I need to create conditions for these types of tests, because TestCafé throws an error on empty strings. Is there a better way?

```js
static async login({ email = '', password = '' }) {
  await t
    .typeText('#email', email)
    .typeText('#password', password)
    .click('#submit');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `pressKey` would work for you? It requires that the input is separated by spaces but doesn't need a selector. [Documentation for pressKey](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/press-key.html)

Example:

```
await t
    .pressKey('u s e r @ t e s t . c o m enter')
    .pressKey('p a s s w o r d enter')
```

I'm making the assumption that `enter` or maybe `tab` would move to the next field, but I think that could also work for your second point

Comment: I didn't know this works. Although it seems a bit hacky it does the job, so thanks a lot! Any idea about the second question?

Comment: @AndreasRemdt Does `.pressKey('enter')` on its own work? Whatever moves it to the next field just without typing first?

Comment: Thinking about it, it could work using `.pressKey('tab')`, avoiding the `.typeText` action altogether. I'll have a look into this.